# Get last n characters of one field and complete second field of a string in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk, cut

I have 2 lines in a file :

```
MUMBAI,918889986665,POSTPAID,CRBT123,CRBT,SYSTEM,151004,MONTHLY,160201,160302
MUMBAI,912398456781,POSTPAID,SEGP,SEGP30,SMS,151004,MONTHLY,160201,160302
```

I wanted to cut field 2 and 4 in above lines. Condition is: from field 2, I need only ten digits.

Desired output:

```
8889986665,CRBT
2398456781,SEGP30
```

I am trying below command :

```
 cut -d',' -f2 test.txt | cut -c3-12 && cut -d',' -f4 test.txt
```

My output:

```
 8889986665
 2398456781
 CRBT
 SEGP30
```

Kindly help me to achieve desired output.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 2:**
Here is the solution which will serve the purpose:

`cut -d',' -f2,4 1  | sed  's/.*\([0-9]\{10\}\),\(.*\)/\1,\2/'`

8889986665,CRBT123

2398456781,SEGP

- `cut` will give us the second and forth field.
- Inside sed, `.*` to skip the initial characters until the first pattern ahead is encountered.
- First pattern is 10 digits followed by a semicolon:
  `\([0-9]\{10\}\),`
- Second pattern is rest of the line: `\(.*\)`
- Now we print both the patterns with semicolon in between: `\1,\2`

Note that the number `10` can replaced by number of characters to be
   extracted before the delimiter `,` `[0-9]` can be replaced by `.` if
   these characters can be any type of characters.

**Solution 1:**

Using `cut` will be easiest for you in this case.

You first need to get desired fields (2,4) filtered from the line and then do more filtering (only 10 characters from field #2)

```
$ cut -d',' -f2,4 test.txt | cut -c3-        
8889986665,CRBT123
2398456781,SEGP
```

Comment: How would one know to use `-c3-`?

Comment: `-c3-` is for the column but even i was not knowing that it will cut until 12th digit.

Comment: That's right `-c3-` cannot be assumed as length of 2nd column can be more than 12 OR can be variable length.

Comment: Yes, the first solution assumed that there will be 12 characters in the second field.
I am posting other generic solution

Answer (score 1):

This is job best done using `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v n=10 '{print substr($2, length($2)-n+1, n) FS $5}' file

8889986665,CRBT
2398456781,SEGP30
```

`substr` command will print last `n` characters in 2nd column.

Comment: Just curious, but why is awk better?

Comment: See my comment below your answer for the reason

Comment: @anubhava the solution works great. However, Rahul Gundecha 's solution is very simple. :)

Comment: That answer is wrong because user has to know `-c3-` upfront. What if length of 2nd column is not 12. There can be variable length as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat test.txt | cut -f 2,4 -d ","
```

assuming your file is test.txt

Comment: Please see my comment below @kometen's answer

Comment: This will fetch me the whole 12 numbers of field number 2 with field number 4. I have a condition before cutting the fields. Refer the question for condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/[^,]+,..([^,]+,)([^,]+,)([^,]+),.*/\1\3/' file
8889986665,CRBT123
2398456781,SEGP
```